# NodeJs - Cache-Control header doesnt work correctly

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node server which sets the Cache control to max-age=6200.

But everytime i call the same request it doesnt check the cache but makes the request again. 
It was supposed to return 304 not modified.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=6200");
  res.send("Hello");
});
```

What did i do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Cache work for static assets, like .js, .html, .jpg... Your application don't return a statis asset.

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX So you are telling me that i cant cache a json response?

Comment: have a look to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage